# eigenvalues of the drift matrix in an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a multidimensional stochastic process $X_t$ which satisfies a stochastic differential equation of the form

$$dX_t = A(X_t-m)dt + SdB_t$$

with matrices $A,B$ and a vector $m$ (Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process). I'd like to estimate the eigenvalues of $A$ using a discrete sample. If I use an estimator for $A$ (MLE for example) and its eigenvalues I might need a lot of data. Also, a lot of research here is based on symmetric matrices or at least matrices with independent entries, which might not be true for estimators of $A$.

Is it possible to estimate the eigenvalues without estimating $A$? Which statistical properties would these estimators have?

Comment: In this paper, https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=38hcUMUAAAAJ&citation_for_view=38hcUMUAAAAJ:2osOgNQ5qMEC, we estimate the eigenvalues of A using a Bayesian way.